Websites for extensive research on a specific bike

The picture above is of my 2007 Z20 Haro with the V-Brake setup I have got it taken apart since I'm going to be customizing it to what my vision is
Ok I have done some research and finally determined that my bike is a 2007 Z20 Haro 20" bicycle. I found some information on the bike but it was only from the official Haro website itself and there wasn't a whole lot of information I was really trying to find out some good websites to look for more information about my bike as well as possibly being able to locate a full detailed list of the parts of my bike and their measurements. But I'm not exactly sure where to start other than the Haro website

After such a long time the exact names of the parts are not very useful anyway. You willl have to find something that fits and is compatible with the rest.

BMX parts are a big mess.  You have the bike, its yours, so you can do what you want with it to make it better for you.   There is no real value in a concours rebuild, cos you'd never ride it.

Here is a link to the 2007 Haro catalog.

Parts list


I already have this list of parts but I was wanting more extensive research on the 07' Haro Z20

@JoMama In your question you specifically ask about a list of parts. If you would provide a list of what you want when you say "more extensive research" it would help us provide the answer you seek.

I am mainly wanting websites that have more Information about the 2007 Haro Z-20 itself not so much about the parts list anymore but just like general info and like websites where I can get custom colo specific replacement parts for it at an affordable price

Well, you have the bike in front of you. You have the original spec from the Haro website.
If you need to make a measurement, vernier calipers are useful.
Many parts can be one of only a few sizes or types so identification is quite easy.
Haro only make the frame and it has to conform to the industry standards for the components they have chosen to fit -- but there are a wide variety of fully compatible alternatives to any given component.
You need to work out which specific components are causing you to worry about spec, identify alternatives available on the market and compare or question the measurements you've taken.
